# How to get the history of Function in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I have created a Function in Oracle Database. Now by mistake, I have changed that function. I have removed a few things inside it. Is there any way to restore the old Function.

I have checked and found that there is a possibility to recover the Database table from Flashback command. But is there any way to recover the Function?

Comment: Here's a learning moment. PL/SQL is source code and should be managed in a source control repository like any other program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try a flashback query while connected as `SYS`:

```
select s.text
from   dba_source as of timestamp timestamp '2018-07-31 00:00:00' s
where  s.owner = 'YOURSCHEMA'
and    s.name = 'YOURFUNCTION'
order by s.line;
```

You must be connected as `SYS` to do this, as `DBA_OBJECTS` is a view over internal system tables such as `USER$`, `OBJ$`, `SOURCE$`, `X$JOXCD` etc, which you won't have access to as a regular user.

This will typically let you go back a few minutes or hours, depending on your [`undo_retention`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/UNDO_RETENTION.html) setting (default is 15 minutes) and how much DML the instance is doing.

Comment: Getting an error "ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 3 with name "_SYSSMU3_1488214942$" too small
01555. 00000 -  "snapshot too old: rollback segment number %s with name \"%s\" too small"
*Cause:    rollback records needed by a reader for consistent read are
           overwritten by other writers
*Action:   If in Automatic Undo Management mode, increase undo_retention
           setting. Otherwise, use larger rollback segments"

Comment: That means the old version is not available in flashback, so you are out of luck, sorry. Is the code not in a source control system? Perhaps it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the Help @William Robertson.